# PHP caching class

Tags: php

I'm a AS3 coder and i do a bit of php and i am having a hard time doing a static class that can cache variables.

Here's what i have so far :

```
<?php
class Cache {

private static $obj;

public static function getInstance() {
    if (is_null(self::$obj)){
        $obj = new stdClass();
    }
    if (!self::$instance instanceof self) { 
        self::$instance = new self;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public static function set($key,$value){
  self::$obj->$key = $value;
}

public static function get($key){
  return  self::$obj->$key;
}
}
?>
```

And i use the following to set my variable into an object of my static class :

```
<?php 
include 'cache.php';
$cache = new Cache();
$cache->set("foo", "bar");
?>
```

And this is retrieve the variable

```
 <?php 
include 'cache.php';
$cache = new Cache();
$echo = $cache->get("foo");
echo $echo //doesn't echo anything
?>
```

What am i doing wrong ? Thank you

Comment: Your issue here is that you're trying to construct a singleton, but you **cannot** instantiate it. When you set `foo`, you're storing the value in that particular instance. But you're creating a new instance when you want to retrieve it.

Comment: @fuzzyDunlop , ok i see so i went $cache = Cache::getInstance();
$cache->set("foo", "bar"); to set and $cache = Cache::getInstance();
echo $cache->get("foo"); still doesn't work :(

Comment: In this code, your `get` and `set` methods are `static`, so you need to use `::` instead of `->` when calling them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've adapted @prodigitalson's code above to get something rudimentary that works (and has much room for improvement):

```
class VarCache {
  protected static $instance;
  protected static $data = array();

  protected function __construct() {}

  public static function getInstance() {
     if(!self::$instance) {
       self:$instance = new self();
     }

     return self::$instance;
  }

  public function get($key) {
     self::getInstance();

     return isset(self::$data[$key]) ? self::$data[$key] : null;
  }

  public function set($key, $value) {
     self::getInstance();
     self::$data[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
VarCache::set('foo', 'bar');
echo VarCache::get('foo');
// 'bar'
```

You'll want this class to be available everywhere you need it, and if you want it to persist between requests, I'd consider using [`Memcached`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) or something similar, which will give you everything you need.

You could alternatively use some `SPL` functions, like [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), if you wanted to be clever :)

Comment: Indeed Memcache (without the D - I'm on WAMP) was what i really needed. I just installed it and it rules. For people like me on WAMP who want to install it as well, check this out : http://shikii.net/blog/installing-memcached-for-php-5-3-on-windows-7/

Comment: @mrlee what kind of "room for improvement" do you think of ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class VarCache {
  protected $instance;
  protected $data = array();
  protected __construct() {}

  public static function getInstance()
  {
     if(!self::$instance) {
       self:$instance = new self();
     }

     return self::$instance;
  }

  public function __get($key) {
     return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : null;
  }

  public function __set($key, $value) {
     $this->data[$key] = $value;
  }
}

// usage

VarCache::getInstance()->theKey = 'somevalue';
echo VarCache::getInstance()->theKey;
```